# Cyclone V external memory group pins DQ/DQS

Tags: fpga, pinout, cyclone

I'm trying to understand the functions of external memory pins  in Cyclone V (5csema5af31c6n) 
I do understand that colums HMC Pin Assignment for DDR3/DDR2/LPDDR2 shows pin functions for external memory implementation (using hard memory controller). But for what DQS x8 and DQS x 16 colums? Is this some interface? Why some functions are duplicated? Can't understand it even reading Cyclone V handbook (chapter External Memory Interfaces in Cyclone V Devices) and External Memory Interface Handbook.
[Pinout file for 5CSEMA5AF31C6N](https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/dp/cyclone-v/5csema5.xls)
[image: This is screenshot from related pinout file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two way of handling DDR Memory on a Cyclone V featuring a HPS and a HMC:

- Using the HMC (Hard Memory Controller) sitting in the FPGA part
- Using the HPS's memory controller (which is also available with FPGA not featuring a HMC)

This explain why on columns "HMC" you have two sets of DDR signals, one beginning by B_xyz is for the HMC and the other one beginning by HPS_xyz is for the HPS controller. This is easy to understand I agree.

But there is also a third way to control DDR memory, through a soft memory controller, in the FPGA part (with ALTMEM_PHY IP I guess), thus you can use I/O pins for this controller. I/O pins are general use and can't achieve high DDR frequency, but Altera tried to optimize the internal routing of these pins to achieve a decent memory speed.

Thus As this is the FPGA part and general I/O you can choose your own pinout... within limits. These limits are specified by the DQS x8 or DQS x16 column:

All pins of a DQx group should be in a DQx group of the pin list. If we take a DQ[0...7] / DQS-DQSn0 group and you want it on group DQS4B of the DQS x8 column, then:

- DQS0 = AB15 (DQS4B)
- DQSn0 = AC14 (DQSn4B)
- DQ[0...7] are placed as you want between DQS4B pins: AG13, AJ6, AG12, AK8, AK9, AH14, AJ9, AH13.

I'm currently using a Cyclone V SE but without HMC and without soft memory controller, so please contact Altera for more details or try some pinout in Quartus.

Answer (score 1):

It is the bus width. See [this](https://www.micron.com/~/media/documents/products/data-sheet/dram/ddr1/1gb_ddr.pdf) IC. Look at the pinout on page 9.

You just need to ensure that you use the correct DQS pins for your bus width. I guess they have some timing constraints.

Comment: Ok but... let's consider this situation. If I want to wire your IC with my FPGA using HMC I should do it with pins in HMC column and there is quite understandable if I look in pinout file. However I still don't understand why this pins in DQS x8 and DQS x 16 colums are duplicated? And what about soft implementation? Can I use any I/O pin for any IC pin? And DQS pins as far as I know has no any timing constraints.

Comment: Some work for both modes, that is why they are duplicated. Simple rule: select DQS pins that support your chosen mode. You still need DQ and DQS for the soft controller too, because it uses the hard IOs. The best way to check is to synthesize the design. If you have invalid pin placement, the place and route will fail with appropriate messages. I always recommend synthesis before layout because some things are not documented well in the data sheets, or are difficult to find. At least try a top level design with just the memory controller, or download one of their designs and swap the pins.